# react-native-autogrow-textinput: cannot find symbol editText.setBlurOnSubmit(false)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

While running my RN project I get on the react-native-autogrow-textinput after upgrading it to react-native-autogrow-textinput: ^5.4.0
Here's the error:

```js
error: cannot find symbol
                editText.setBlurOnSubmit(false);
                        ^
  symbol:   method setBlurOnSubmit(boolean)
  location: variable editText of type ReactEditText
```

And here is my android/build.gradle

```js
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        supportLibVersion = "34.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.0"
    }

    subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
        repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I have not been able to figure out how to resolve this issue; any help is appreciated.